# seralizing EF entities; disabling Proxy Creation and Lazy Loading?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Ive been having some problems regarding circular references when converting EF entities to json objects. I have found a solution that works for me, but i would like to know what is actually happening when im adding

```
 context.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

and/or

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

The first one seems to be enough to get a single-dimensional json object. Should i use both? And what does they actually do? Is there a smarter way around this? Thanks

Comment: I noticed from your last post that you are using JavaScriptSerializer..is there a specific reason for this? Is this for a web application? I think you should take a different approach to getting your json, such as DataContractJsonSerializer or the Json.NET library.

Comment: @SeanThoman I've tried using json.net, but still got the circular reference exception. This is a normal asp.net 4.0 web forms app. Do you have any examples using the DataContractJsonSerializer?

Comment: Disabling proxy creation automatically disables lazy loading, even if you explicitly set LazyLoadingEnabled to true..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First line turns off runtime generation of class that inherits from your entity class. This class is really used during runtime. Not your class. This runtime generated class is probably not Serializable and that's why this line (turning off proxy generation) makes serialization work.

Second line turns off lazy loading. So let's say you have Parent entity and Child entity. When you ask for Parent you don't load Children when lazy loading is on. When it is off whenever you load Parent you load all of it's children. I think this is something you should familiarize with if you are using EF.

Edit:
If there is problem with circular reference then you should turn off lazy loading. Then when you serialize Parent you will not try to serialize Children that have reference to Parent (creating circular reference)

Comment: Okay, but should disable lazy loading do the trick alone then?

Comment: Like you said. First line is enough.

Comment: Yea, i just dont understand why disabling lazy loading is enough. Shouldnt that remove the relations to other entities?

Comment: Ah ok. A final question: Will i still be able to use the EF intellisense to select different entities based on eachother (foreign keys) regardless of if i set ProxyCreationEnabled to false?

Comment: Intellisense has nothing to do with proxy classes or lazy loading.

Comment: I want to know if theres a way to keep the link between entities when disabling lazy loading.

Comment: There is a link. But you have to load related entities explicitly. Using Load method or Include method - http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/03/10/lazy-loading-eager-loading-explicit-loading-in-entity-framework-4.aspx. You can upvote answer if you find it useful.